# Unexplained error in JS

Tags: javascript

This is the code:

```
var k ;
function getrandom()
{
    k = Math.random()*2 ;
    alert(k);
}
```

Hello I've searched a lot to see why this simple JS code is not working. I appreciate your help.
Thank You.

Comment: You really didn't say what went wrong...

Comment: There's nothing in this code to "not work." Please post a sufficiently complete example, and describe what you mean by "not working."

Comment: Works fine... http://jsfiddle.net/AWET6/

Comment: The reason why you can't find why it's not working is because it works.

Comment: The code you post looks correct (syntactically). It might not do what you want, but as we don't know what you want, we cannot help you with that.

Comment: What this code does is set the variable k to some number between 0 and 2; then shows it to the user in an alert. I see nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you forgot to call it.

```
var k;   

function getrandom()
{    
    k = Math.random() * 2;
    alert(k);
}

getrandom();
```

Comment: Sadly I can't up this (unless asker agrees) but if this were facebook I would definitely 'like' it!

Answer (score 1):

If I execute your snippet and invoke `getrandom()` it alerts a random number between 0 and 2. Is that not what the program is supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't call this function?

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MRcmF/

It works!

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to do something like this:

```
function getrandom(max) {
    alert(Math.round(Math.random()*max)) ;
}
getrandom(10);
```

Comment: Well, the code certainly isn't "not working", seems more like a logic error than a syntax one, so taking an educated guess.